# Is possible to access $loader variable I see in the debug window?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, classloader

As you can see in this screenshot while I'm in debug mode i can see a $loader variable that has the "() -> com.belandsoft.orariGTT.Model.RestRequestResponse, kotlin.Boolean>" content. It's possible to access these value at runtime in any way? The reflection can be helpfull in any way?

Sample code:

```
val mCollection: kotlin.collections.HashMap<Int, () -> Unit> = HashMap()

fun <T> myAddFunction(loader: () -> T) {
    val elementCode = loader?.hashCode()

    if (elementCode != null) {
        mCollection[elementCode] = loader
    }
}

fun myPrintFunction(): String {
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var index = 0
    for (i in mCollection.iterator()) {
         stringBuilder.append("$index:[${i.value}] ")
         index++
    }
    stringBuilder.toString()
}
```

This sadly produces a string like:

"053523:[()->kotlin.Unit], 453455:[()->kotlin.Unit]"

but I want to have:

"053523:[()->com.belandsoft.orariGTTView.MainFragment$startPtArrivalSearch$2$18839], 453455:[()->com.belandsoft.orariGTTView.MainFragment$startPtArrivalSearch$2$18845]"

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: @Lino obviously not. you cannot use $ as member or function names

Comment: Normally this variable represents a captured local variable, which you can access using its regular name (`loader`). Posting a snippet of the actual code you're debugging will help answer this more specifically.

Comment: @yole I just added a sample code snippet to a better problem understanding